# C string value destroyed when function returns

Tags: c, memory, malloc

So I have this function:

```
char    *ft_string(char *s, int *i) {
int     j;
char    *res;

j = *i;
res = NULL;
while (s[j] && s[j] != ' ' && s[j] != '\"' && s[j] != '\'' && s[j] != '$')
{
    if (s[j] == '\\')
        ft_remove_char(s, j);
    j++;
}
res = ft_substr(s, *i, j - *i);
(*i) = j - 1;
return (res);
```

that calls ft_remove char:

```
void    ft_remove_char(char *s, int i){
char    *ret;
int     j;

ret = malloc((int)ft_strlen(s) * sizeof(char) + 1);
if (ret == NULL)
    return ;
j = -1;
while (++j < i)
    ret[j] = s[j];
i = j;
while (s[++j])
{
    ret[i] = s[j];
    i++;
}
ret[j - 1] = '\0';
if (s)
    free(s);
s = ret;
```

When ft_remove_char returns, s value disappear in ft_string.
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, I allocate a string on the heap and then make s point to it.

Comment: format your code first.

Comment: 2. Describe what whose function should do. Sample input and example output.

Comment: you have more `ft_*` functions you call. All of them can cause the provbem

Comment: Inside `ft_remove_char()` you cannot change `s` of `ft_string()`, since you pass it by value.

Comment: s is destroyed right after ft_remove_char returns so I'm sure that the problem come from there.

Comment: How come I can free it but not modify it, should I pass it as a char ** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters in C are passed by value. Function `ft_remove_char` receives a **copy** of pointer `s`. So, when it overwrites `s`, it does not affect the `s` in `ft_string`.

Instead, try returning the modified `s` from `ft_remove_char` and change the call in `ft_string` to:

```
s = ft_remove_char(s, j);
```

This is quite idiomatic in C.

NOTE: This only answers your question. I have not verified your code is correct.

Comment: It seems to work, I tried it before but probably did it wrong.

Comment: Thanks mate appreciate your help